# yii form submit button also set validation and change model value

Tags: php, yii

I have one form contain publication_date, somethings and submit button

```
 <?= CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', array('class' => 'btn-green')); ?>
```

Now I want to click the submitButton to submit the form, and also check whether the publication_date is equal to today.
If it's not today it will pop up a window contains two button yes, no  say whether you want to change the publication_date to today.

I'm no idea about how to popup window cause by submitbutton and how this window can also set the model->publication_date value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion, I think it would be better to handle it via java-script/JQuery:

```
$("YOUR_FORM_SELECTOR_NAME").on("submit",function(){
    var userEnteredDate=$("YOUR_DATE_SELECTOR_NAME").val();
    //since I do not know what is your date format, I skip the date comparison.
    //var today=new Date(); ... //in yout format
    if(userEnteredDate !=today){
         var confirmation=confirm("The entered date is not today, would you like it to change?");
         return !confirmation; // it does not let the form to be submitted if user click on ok 
    }
});
```

The code might not be sufficient, I said it just as an Idea

Comment: Thanks, can you explain more detail. In var userEnterrdDate, i want to let it = model->publication_date. And if not equal today, it should has two button (Yes: set to today, No use the old date)

Comment: And when click form submit button it need pop up a window (if not equal today), it should has two button (Yes: set to today, No use the old date)

Comment: In this case I suggest you Jquery UI dialog or any Jquery/Javascript Modal plugin. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/‎

Comment: And about `userEnteredDate`, so sorry, I modified my answer.

Comment: my userEnteredDate is in the yii $model, but i can't directly use $model->publication_date. it shows error